# How to get the names of all properties (without their values) in a json object?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a json object, a string, that contains some properties and their values. Say I never know what comes in my json object, how can I loop though it and get what properties it contains? For example:

{
"aaaa": 1,
"bbbb": "qwerty",
"ccc": 21.22
}

How do I collect aaa, bbb and ccc? Once again, I don't want their values, I just want the name of the properties.

Comment: Is your json always flat? Or could it be that "bbbb" is a subproperty of "aaaa" for example.

Comment: Good question! Yes, it's always flat!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's as simple as this:

```
var json = @"{ ""aaaa"": 1, ""bbbb"": ""qwerty"", ""ccc"": 21.22 }";
var jobject = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(json);
var names = jobject.Root.Cast<JProperty>().Select(x => x.Name).ToArray();
```

That gives:

```
aaaa
bbbb
ccc
```

Answer (score 2):

Deserialize the json to `Dictionary` using `JsonConvert`

> Note: This will work if the key are always unique

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(jsonString);
Console.WriteLine($"{string.Join(",", result.Keys)}");
```

Answer (score 0):

just in one line

```
IEnumerable<string> names = JObject.Parse(json).Properties().Select(x => x.Name);
```

this will include the names of nested objects properties

```
IEnumerable names = JObject.Parse(json).Descendants().OfType<JProperty>()
                                                           .Select(x => x.Name);
```